# ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined FOR pharmacyschema.sql (RX pharmacies Database)

Tags: sql, oracle, join

```
SQL> Select PCompany.CName, CPhone from PCOMPANY
  2  INNER JOIN SELLS on PCOMPANY.CNAME = SELLS.CNAME
  3  INNER JOIN Pharmacy on Sells.PhName = Pharmacy.PhName
  4  WHERE
  5  PHNAME = 'Shoppers';
```

PHNAME = 'Shoppers'
*
ERROR at line 5:
ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined

The question asks: Specify the following 5 queries in SQL on the Pharmacy record database schema of Figure 1.1.

i. List all your 5 queries in the table below first in SQL.

Comment: Error text is very precise to identify the reason. How oracle will know which `PHNAME` you want to use? You can look at join condition and see that there are at least two sources for it.

Comment: Select PCompany.CName, CPhone from PCompany 
INNER JOIN Sells ON PCompany.CName = Sells.CName 
INNER JOIN Pharmacy ON Sells.PHNAME = Pharmacy.PHNAME
WHERE Pharmacy.PHNAME = 'Shoppers'; /*This fixed the issue*/

Comment: As you were advised in answers it is a good practice to give your column a full name (`<table name>.<column name>`) to save your and some readers's future time. When after years your "always working" application accidentally stopped working, because someone decided he or she need the same column in another table or you need to guess, where did that column come from in 1000 lines script with 10 tables in join

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the line

```
PHNAME = 'Shoppers';
```

There are two `PHNAME` columns in the tables in this query, `Sells.PhName` and `Pharmacy.PhName`. You need to specify which of these `PHNAME` columns you wish to check - so that last line should be either

```
Sells.PHNAME = 'Shoppers';
```

or

```
Pharmacy.PHNAME = 'Shoppers';
```

Answer (score 0):

Now you know the issue with your code as correctly mentioned in another answer.

You need to know that using table alias/name before the column is the most important thing else Oracle will get confused that which column you are referring to if that column is present in more than one table that is used in the `JOIN`.

But there are multiple ways to do `JOIN`s

- Using the `ON` clause, You must have to provide the table name/alias before common column names.
- But with the `USING` clause, Oracle allows/enforces you not to use the table alias/name before common column names.

Example with `ON` clause: (See inline comments in the code)

```
SELECT PCOMPANY.CNAME, -- WITH ALIAS NAME OF TABLE PCOMPANY OR SELLS
       PCOMPANY.CPHONE -- ALIAS NAME OF RELEVANT TABLE, PCOMPANY IS ASSUMPTION FOR ME
  FROM PCOMPANY
 INNER JOIN SELLS ON SELLS.CNAME = PCOMPANY.CNAME 
 INNER JOIN PHARMACY ON PHARMACY.PHNAME = SELLS.PHNAME 
 WHERE SELLS.PHNAME = 'Shoppers'; -- WITH ALIAS NAME OF TABLE SELLS/PHARMACY
```

Example with `USING` clause: (See inline comments in the code)

```
SELECT CNAME, -- WITHOUT ALIAS NAME OF TABLE AS THIS COLUMN IS USED IN THE USING CLAUSE
       PCOMPANY.CPHONE -- FOLLOW THE PRACTISE OF GIVING TABLE ALIAS NAME
  FROM PCOMPANY
 INNER JOIN SELLS USING (CNAME) -- USED THE USING ON CNAME COLUMN
 INNER JOIN PHARMACY USING (PHNAME) -- USED THE USING ON PHNAME COLUMN
 WHERE PHNAME = 'Shoppers'; -- WITHOUT ALIAS NAME OF TABLE AS THIS COLUMN IS USED IN THE USING CLAUSE
```